# Variadic function - how to get number of var_args?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Can this be done at all?  Is there, for example, some sort of `va_num_args`?

Basically, I am logging events across  a serial port in a `prinf()` like manner, taking a format string and, optional ly, some arguments. I would like to know if there are any such option arguments present.

E.g, can I distinguish between `Trace("No paramters here");` and `Trace("forty two = %d", 43 - 1);` ?

Comment: Generally you don't. You typically pass in other parameters which determine how many additional arguments were passed in. e.g., a format string (printf) or an explicit argument count.

Comment: You cannot. It's not available information. Thus the popularity of APIs that require an extra 0 at the end.

Comment: `printf` does it by examining the format string.

Comment: or you scan through the arg list twice: once to get count, then  again to process params...

Comment: GCC has an extension to do type checking of parameters against a function that is `printf` like. See http://ideone.com/h8Qz11

Comment: @SethCarnegie If you submit that as an answer, I can accept it. It works, not for the general case (how many varargs?), but for my printf() like case, becase I can just scan the format string for a % character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but the following methods can be used instead:

- Deduce argument cound from a format string (like `printf`).
- Use a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to indicate last argument.
- Supply a dedicated count argument.